# universal navbar and sidebar HTML

Tags: php, html

im new to web development and this might sound pretty stupid but i really find it annoying to constantly copy & paste my navbar & sidebar to different php files so they would all have a navbar & sidebar, so when change something to the two i will have to copy & paste the changes to all the other php files so they would all be the same.

so can anyone teach on the proper way to make a nav & side bar without having to copy & paste them to different php files and so that i can edit them in one place??

Comment: Put them in their own files and use [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) to include them where you need them.

Comment: try to create 1 php files for your navbar & sidebar. and using `include` or `require` in another file to call your navbar & sidebar.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ill try it

Comment: @illuminarch is that how professionals normally do it?

Comment: I'm not sure. But, is professional wasting time to edit many navbar & sidebar for every changes in each file? i think no. I choose more `efficient way` than title `how professional you do it?`

Comment: it worked guys thanks a lot

Comment: @J.Doe - essentially, but that is the most basic way.  The way I do it involves a template wrapper but underneath thats basically what it does.  Generally the template engine will load them using `file_get_contents` and then it parses the template and replaces variable place holders and such `{var}`  The reason it's done that way is to remove PHP from the HTML, so that it's much cleaner to work with. It's a mess in big project to include business logic in your presentation. And its much harder to maintain or have non PHP programmers write front end code. You could have a guy just do front end.

Comment: Most "professional" I know use template engines like Twig, Plates or similar.

Comment: Another big reason is to escape possible HTML in your output (`XSS` hacks etc.).  Most template engines do this basically by default.  If you know prepared statements in the DB its kind of like that but for HTML.

Comment: i see, template wrappers/engines. im currently working on a school project that includes a database and stuff right now i have my hands full on working with the project while learning the proper way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include (or require ) statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement. Including files is very useful when you want to include the same PHP, HTML, or text on multiple pages of a website.

### - check the link below

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include2

Comment: @J.Doe - There is no single way that "professionals" do it. It usually depend on the professional and the requirements of the application. However, most people I know (me included) tend to use template engines instead of handling views/templates manually.

Comment: Yes exactly because its professional way defined by PHP developers.
follow the link that is given in answer you will learn a lot.you may up vote this answer..Thanks

Comment: I would rather recommend using a template engine, like Magnus suggested.

Comment: @MubeenKhan i tried to upvote the answer and the site displayed this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."